# View Images in Carto

Tags: image

For 120 datasets, which I already loaded into carto and are shown where they are supposed to be shown, I want images to be viewed as well.

In my thinking it should have been enough to put in an URL for each dataset in the "image_url" field but it won't work... Is there a simple explanation, what I can do? Do I need html-skills, which I don't have...?

I want pictures for every dataset...so simple :-)